# Server (with Postfix) is forwarding my email using a .forward file, is it still saved on the server?

Tags: email, postfix

I'm using Postfix on my server but not really using that for much because I have a .forward file setup for all accounts which forwards the email to someplace else, and never sending through the server.

So I just want to know if Postfix or anything would still be saving copies of the received emails anywhere. I looked in some of the obvious places but couldn't find anything.

Edited: Output of postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command = 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = {redacted}
myhostname = {redacted}
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = 
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

Comment: can you post the output of `postconf -n`, that will help to find if postfix is also sending/storing it somewhere else.

Comment: @clement see edits above